# In loadrunner, How to collate result if one of the load generator got failed during collation of result?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I have executed performance test on load runner. During the collation of result one of my load generator got crashed and controller unalbe to fetch result from that LG. So how can I collate the result now from that particualr LG and merge it with my result?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to understand your exact situation from the question but here are two possible solutions:

1) Try manual collate from the controller - You can find more details about it here - https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.60/help/WebHelp/Content/Controller/t_collate_results.htm

2) Get the files from the LG. To determine where the files are saved in the Load Generators view select the LG with the problem and click details. A dialog will open displaying the Temporary directory, you can find the results there.

More information on this method can be found here - https://easyloadrunner.blogspot.com/2013/06/manual-results-collation-in-loadrunner.html